# VBA Pivot Table- Datafields Horizontal to Vertical

Tags: vba, sum, format, pivot, pivot-table

I've been following a book on how to create a pivot table using VBA.
The code in the book works fine and it's doing what it's supposed to be doing. But i don't understand how to change how the Datafields are displayed.
It's listing the datafields horizontally one on top of the other in One column.
I want to know how to get the datafields to appear in separate columns (in the datafield area)

Here is the book's code:

```
Sub CreatePivot2()
    ' Create pivot table at active cell
    ' Assumes that the source table is in sheet called Source
    ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:="'Source'!R1C1:R145C7", _
    TableName:="Sales&Trans2"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sales&Trans2").AddFields _
    RowFields:=Array("Store City", "Store Type"), _
    ColumnFields:="Period", _
    PageFields:="Year"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Sales&Trans2")
    With .PivotFields("Transactions")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With .PivotFields("Sales")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .Position = 2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Can you guys tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hope someone can help me figure out this problem..... It drives me crazy.....

Comment: share the current result you are getting with this code (a screen-shot of the Pivot Table), and add a description how you want it to look like (maybe you can simulate manualy and add another screen-shot of the desired result)